# Деление списка с датами на группы по дням недели

Tags: алгоритм, java

Задачка. Есть список дат. Нужно поделить на группы по дням.

Например есть 3 записи в понедельник, 5 во вторник и т.д., все они в одном списке, а на выходе надо 1 список за понедельник, 1 за вторник и т.д., т.е. выбрать из списка списки записей за каждый день недели.

Comment: навеяло текстом вопроса: берем список, добавляем даты, делим, получаем результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разделяет список дат на несколько списков по днях недели:

```
public class SplitDates
{
    private static int INPUT = 5 ;

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // generate input list
        List < Date > input = createInputList () ;

        dump ( "input:", input ) ;

        // days array (numbering starts from 1)
        String[] days = new String[] { "", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" } ;

        // create result map
        Map < Integer, List < Date >> result = new HashMap < Integer, List < Date > > () ;

        // split dates by day of week
        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance () ;
        for ( Date i : input )
        {
            // configure calendar
            instance.setTime ( i ) ;

            // get day of week
            int j = instance.get ( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) ;

            // put date to the proper list
            List < Date > list = result.get ( j ) ;
            if ( null == list )
            {
                list = new LinkedList < Date > () ;
                result.put ( j, list ) ;
            }
            list.add ( i ) ;
        }

        // display results
        for ( Entry < Integer, List < Date >> e : result.entrySet () )
        {
            dump ( "output '" + days[e.getKey ()] + "' :", e.getValue () ) ;
        }
    }

    private static void dump ( String message, List < Date > data )
    {
        System.out.println ( message ) ;
        if ( null != data )
        {
            for ( Date date : data )
            {
                System.out.println ( date ) ;
            }
        }
        System.out.println () ;
    }

    private static List < Date > createInputList ()
    {
        // result list
        List < Date > result = new LinkedList < Date > () ;

        // date init
        long init = System.currentTimeMillis () ;

        // create randomizer
        Random random = new Random ( init ) ;

        // fill list with random dates
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < INPUT ; i++ )
        {
            // random offset (date in the past/feature)
            int sign = (int) Math.signum ( random.nextInt ( 10 ) - 5 ) ;

            // date offset
            long offset = random.nextInt ( 1000 ) ;

            result.add ( new Date ( init + sign * offset * 999999 ) ) ;
        }

        return result ;
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
input:
Thu Aug 09 04:59:36 EEST 2012
Sun Aug 26 14:12:54 EEST 2012
Mon Aug 27 10:46:14 EEST 2012
Sun Aug 19 00:49:35 EEST 2012
Thu Aug 23 23:26:14 EEST 2012

output 'Sunday' :
Sun Aug 26 14:12:54 EEST 2012
Sun Aug 19 00:49:35 EEST 2012

output 'Monday' :
Mon Aug 27 10:46:14 EEST 2012

output 'Thursday' :
Thu Aug 09 04:59:36 EEST 2012
Thu Aug 23 23:26:14 EEST 2012
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно за что минус. Если что-то не так пишите, разберемся :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот алгоритм из RSDN, имеются и другие:

```
a = (14 − месяц) / 12;
y = год − a;
m = месяц + 12 * a − 2;
ДеньНедели = (7000 + (день + y + y / 4 − y / 100 + y / 400 + (31 * m) / 12)) ОСТАТОК 7;
```

Все деления целочисленные.

Результат: 0 — воскресенье, 1 — понедельник и т. д.

Comment: я вообще-то почти сразу решил это, но интересно кто как может еще это реализовать... и задача не в том, что бы определить день недели, а в том что бы сгруппировать данные по дням, например есть 3 записи в понедельник, 5 - вторник и тд, все они в одном списке, а надо 1 список за понедельник, 1 за вторник и тд.. т.е. выбрать из списка списки записей за каждый день

Comment: Если не сложно поделитесь своим решением в нескольких словах, как вы делали группирование.

Comment: код на работе, но попробую коротко рассказать основной принцип.

1. Запоминаю дату первого элемента в переменной и создаю пустой список в котором будут записи за этот день.

2. Беру 2й и тд и сравниваю его дату с переменной +1 день.

3. Если меньше - добавляю запись в список.

4. Если равно - создаю новые список для нового дня, присваиваю переменной эту дату, добавляю заполненный массив в Мар, где ключ - дата, значение - массив записей за эту дату.

Comment: Просто неделю назад пришлось группировать данные не много другого типа, поэтому было интересно, правильный был подход или нет ) Так или иначе суть используемого метода совпадает. Спасибо

Comment: А сразу сделать 7 пустых списков, тупо заполнить их и потом удалить оставшиеся пустыми не проще ?

Comment: как заполнить? а если там записей только для одного дня? тогда 6 лишние, в моем варианте они создаются по надобности и не надо думать над тем, что бы при появлении записей для нового дня брался новый список..

Comment: @Gorets, ну известно, что программа, которую только пишешь - самая лучшая.

Comment: Причем тут это? Просто я не вижу смысла создавать 7 пустых списков с самого начала, если ты покажешь пример или/и обоснуешь чем это лучше - я соглашусь и все переделаю.

Comment: @Gorets, вот переделывать только не надо. 

IMHO просто использовать Map (динамически) для нескольких (малого числа) заранее перечисляемых сущностей - это "из пушки по воробьям".

Собственно это (аналогичный стиль программирования, стремление постоянно использовать общие подходы) просто беда, системы потом неподъемные (и не только (даже не столько) в смысле производительности) получаются.

Comment: @Gorets, изначальное ваше *задание* никак не стыкуется с той, решение для которой вы тут написали, собственно какой вопрос - такой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я наверно, не понял задачи, иначе проходит такое решение: заводим 7 списков, по списку на день, идем по данному в условии списку, добавляем каждую запись в нужный список. Быстрее вроде никак.

Comment: Избыточный алгоритм. А если тебе надо по дням года разбить? Будешь 365 списков заводить на каждый год?

Comment: А почему бы и нет? Это будет работать быстрее, чем Map. Еще раз, использовать Map для 7 значений: крайне спорный подход.